# Statusbar Manager Android

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I cant find the code for statusbar manager in android code, i have tried the cyanogen github but with no luck.

Does anyone knows where to find (or look) for the statusbarmanager's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should look at:

```
/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java
```